# Is there a way of optimizing this python try, except loop?

Tags: python, optimization, try-catch

In general, the code consists in having a list of lists (`series_`) where, using the initial value of the list as a base, the first value of each list that meets certain criteria is searched.

However some lists do not contain values ​​that meet that criterion (where the exception works and adds an arbitrary value to the `Compra_` list).
I'd be interested in optimizing the `try`/`except` part since I'm working with millions of data and it takes me hours to run the code.

```
for i in range(len(d)):
    series_.append(np.array(data2.Close[d[i]:]))


Compra_ = []
for i in series_:
    try:
        Compra_.append(next(filter(lambda x: x - i[0] >= TH or i[0] - x >= M*TH, i)))
    except:
        Compra_.append(i[0])
```

I know something like this would work, however when the criterion is not met it stops iterating.

```
Compra_ = [next(filter(lambda x: x - i[0] >= TH or i[0] - x >= M*TH, i)) for i in series_]
```

Comment: What exceptions are you catching?

Comment: I am catching the 'StopIteration' exceptions

Comment: Have you used a profiler to see where the bottleneck is? It's easy to waste a lot of time trying to optimize the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function accepts a "default" parameter. You should be able to use it for your needs. Something like:

```py
for i in series_:
    Compra_.append(next(filter(lambda x: x - i[0] >= TH or i[0] - x >= M*TH, i), i[0]))
```

Using threads (or multiprocessing) would also help cut down on your run time. Something like:

```py
from concurrent import futures
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

Compra_ = []
def filter_function(x):
    conditions = [
        x - i[0] >= TH,
        i[0] - x >= M * TH
    ]
    return any(conditions)

with ThreadPoolExecutor as pool:
    future_results = {}
    for i in series_:
        future_results.update(
            {pool.submit(next, filter(filter_function, i), i[0]): i}
        )

    for future in futures.as_completed(future_results):
        try:
            Compra_.append(future.result())
        except Exception as e:
            pass # Handle exception
```

Comment: The CPython global interpreter lock means that only one thread can run at a time. Threads don't speed up CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: That's fair. I mentioned also using multiprocessing but used threads for the example. Just replace the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor` for CPU-bound tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify and reduce the overhead a bit like this:

```
def compra():
    m_th = M*TH
    th = TH
    return [
        next(
            (x for x in xs if x - xs[0] >= th or xs[0] - x >= m_th),
            xs[0]
        )
        for xs in series_
    ]

Compra_ = compra()
```

This uses the default argument for `next()`, avoids the overhead of the multiplication each loop, and uses a genexpr instead of a `filter()` call. I wrapped it in a function because locals read faster than globals. Let me know if that's any faster.

Comment: According to the python documentation for [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), filter() is the equivalent to the generator expression. How does the generator expression you provided save versus fitler?

Comment: The original code took about 2.1s running, it improved to 1.2s, such a helpful comment.

Comment: Wow. I also just tested this. Despite the docs claiming equality, the generator is quite a bit faster than the filter function. It also seems more readable. Great suggestion @gilch